# Problems serving GeoTiff using GeoServer and ImageMosaic

Tags: geoserver, gdal, geotiff-tiff, image-mosaic

**Goal**:
I am trying to serve a large (1GB+) GeoTiff file using GeoServer and ImageMosaic.

**Process**:
**iant** have written a simple guide for this, which he proposed as an answer for a [previous and similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22284/whats-the-best-way-to-display-a-huge-aerial-image-using-geoserver).

I have used his *gdal_retile* example and this gave me a folder with lots of tiff files and 8 subfolders (1-8, level 1 having the most zoomed tiles and level 8 a small overview tile).

I created an *ImageMosaic* store in GeoServer 2.1.3 and pointed my URL to the folder containing the tiff files and the 8 subfolders. GeoServer then put 8 files in the same folder.

I published my ImageMosaic store as a layer and when doing a preview inside GeoServer, Java just starts working and I don't know if it will ever finish.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: Try an image pyramid datastore instead of an image mosaic

Comment: **iant**: Write an answer telling me to properly read your guide, and I will accept the answer ;)
*ImagePyramid* seems to work very well and I guess I read *ImageMosaic* everywhere instead of *ImagePyramid* :s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between an image mosaic and an image pyramid.

- A [mosaic](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.6.2/user/tutorials/image_mosaic_plugin/imagemosaic.html) is for stitching together a number of images of the same
  resolution.
- A [pyramid](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html) is a series of increasing resolution tile sets that speed up the display of large images.